# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with Quickblox

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker, quickblox

i have this error when adding other linker flag for Quickblox "-ObjC -lxml2 -lstdc++"

duplicate symbol l108 in:
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBSocialLoginDialog.o)
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBDDAbstractDatabaseLogger.o)
duplicate symbol l109 in:
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBSocialLoginDialog.o)
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBDDAbstractDatabaseLogger.o)
duplicate symbol l084 in:
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBQuery.o)
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBLGeoDataGetRequest.o)
duplicate symbol l084 in:
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBQuery.o)
    /Users/caosx01/Documents/Projects/lemeno-ios/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBLGeoDataFilter.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
and only appear when using iOS device !!
i'm using ios 8.2 and xcode 6.2

Comment: i solve it by replace the new framework with the old one !!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar error. Updating Xcode to 6.4 resolved my problem.